# Controlling parquet transactions

Tags: parquet

I have a (desktop) application that logs high frequency data in sqlite. Our annalists have asked to move to parquet (for domain specific reasons).  I have ported our application, and am getting terrible write performance (very similar performance to commiting sqlite every update, without controlling transactions)

Does parquet have similar transaction control or a similar analogy?

Additional background information-

- In every transaction I have ~1200 columns of data to update
- I defined an entirely "flat" parquet message schema, where everyone entry is `required`
- additionally, I believe that I've ruled out filesystem journaling-like bottlenecks, but if it's relevant, I am testing on `xfs` and would deploy on `ext4`
- and finally (?) this is implemented with the rust implementation of parquet (`"parquet = 0.16.0"`)

I'm happy to fill in any missing gaps, where have I gone wrong in this port?

Answer (score 2):

After researching this further, parameters such as `row_group_size`, `compression`, `encoding`, `page_size`, etc... can all be set using the `WriterPropertiesBuilder`. These can even be configured on a per-column basis.

This did not actually solve my problem but answered the gist of my above question of what and where can we configure parquet FileWriters.